# Getting a list of file and url in a Google Drive folder into a sheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I am trying to get a list of files and url in a folder into a google sheet. I picked up this code but I couldn't implement it. When I run it (replacing appropriate folder name), it still get un-identified. I have give permissions as required. I am just a student trying to speed up my workload. I am very new at this so please be gentle. My other functions in the .gs (at the bottom) seems to work ok.

```
/* Code written by @hubgit 
   <style>.gist table { margin-bottom: 0; }</style><div class="gist-oembed" data-gist="hubgit/3755293.json"></div>
   Updated since DocsList is deprecated 
*/

function listFilesInFolder(folderName) {

  var folder = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(folderName).next();
  var contents = folder.getFiles();
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("H1").setValue(contents.length);
  var file, data, sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  //sheet.clear();
  //sheet.appendRow("a");
  sheet.appendRow(["Name", "Date", "Size", "URL", "Download", "Description", "Type"]);

  for (var i = 0; i < contents.length; i++) {

    file = contents[i];

    if (file.getFileType() == "SPREADSHEET") {
      continue;
    }

    data = [ 
      file.getName(),
      file.getDateCreated(),
      file.getSize(),
      file.getUrl(),
      "https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download&confirm=no_antivirus&id=" + file.getId(),
      file.getDescription(),
      file.getFileType().toString()
    ];

    sheet.appendRow(data);

  }

};
```

My working functions:

```
function sheetCount(){
  return SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheets().length;
}

function SheetIndex2Name(indexPosition){
var spread = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  return spread.getSheets()[indexPosition].getSheetName();  
}
```

Comment: I would use getFolderById(). You also need to read the documentation to learn how to use a file iterator. That loop. Is not going to work for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This part of the code seems to be un-reliable

```
    function listFilesInFolder(folderName) 
    {
       var folder = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(folderName).next();
       var contents = folder.getFiles();
       //More codes
    }
```

So this code is far more reliable without the need of getting/inputting name or ID manually

```
function listFilesInFolder()
{
  thisFileId = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getId();
  var thisFile = DriveApp.getFileById(thisFileId);
  var folder = thisFile.getParents().next(); 
  //More codes
}
```

As long as I know, there are cases that one file is a child of two folders. This code will not run properly in that case.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code from [github](https://gist.github.com/hubgit/3755293):

**Note**: Just change the `Docslist.getFolder` to `DriveApp.getFoldersByName`.

```
function listFilesInFolder(name) {

var folder = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(name);
var contents = folder.getFiles();
var file, data;

var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
sheet.clear();

sheet.appendRow(["Name", "Date", "Size", "URL", "Download", "Description", "Type"]);

for (var i = 0; i < contents.length; i++) {

  file = contents[i];

  if (file.getFileType() == "SPREADSHEET") {
    continue;
  }

  data = [ 
    file.getName(),
    file.getDateCreated(),
    file.getSize(),
    file.getUrl(),
    "https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download&confirm=no_antivirus&id=" + file.getId(),
    file.getDescription(),
    file.getFileType().toString()
  ];

  sheet.appendRow(data);

}
```

};

Parameter:

> **name**  *String*
>
> - the name of the files to find

Return

> **FileIterator** — a collection of all files that are children of
> the current folder and have the given name

For more info:

- [Google Apps Script Folder Class API](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder#getFilesByName(String))

Comment: How do I run this code? Do I have to do anything with the sheet? Or just open the code and run it?